# How to drop the Year-Month-Date from a datetime series in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime series, and I want to only keep the "Hour-Miniute-Second" strings in the series, and drop the Year-Month-Date strings.
So what should I do?

original series:

```
0         2000-12-31 22:12:40
1         2000-12-31 22:35:09
2         2000-12-31 22:32:48
3         2000-12-31 22:04:35
4         2001-01-06 23:38:11
5         2000-12-31 22:37:48
……
```

target:

```
0          22:12:40
1          22:35:09
2          22:32:48
3          22:04:35
4          23:38:11
5          22:37:48
……
```

Preiviously the original series has been already translated from a unix timestamp series by using `pandas.to_datetime()`. But I'm not able to use this method to reach my target:(

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

print (df.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

df['time'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
                 date      time
0 2000-12-31 22:12:40  22:12:40
1 2000-12-31 22:35:09  22:35:09
2 2000-12-31 22:32:48  22:32:48
3 2000-12-31 22:04:35  22:04:35
4 2001-01-06 23:38:11  23:38:11
5 2000-12-31 22:37:48  22:37:48
```

Or cast to `string`, [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select second value of `lists` by `str[1]` :

```
#if dtype of date column is object (obviously string), omit astype
df['time'] = df['date'].astype(str).str.split().str[1]
print (df)
                 date      time
0 2000-12-31 22:12:40  22:12:40
1 2000-12-31 22:35:09  22:35:09
2 2000-12-31 22:32:48  22:32:48
3 2000-12-31 22:04:35  22:04:35
4 2001-01-06 23:38:11  23:38:11
5 2000-12-31 22:37:48  22:37:48
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got some nice answer's already. However, they store them as strings, and you might want to store them as actual `datetime.time` objects:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'date': '2000-12-31 22:12:40'},
    {'date': '2000-12-31 22:35:09'},
    {'date': '2000-12-31 22:32:48'},
    {'date': '2000-12-31 22:04:35'},
    {'date': '2001-01-06 23:38:11'},
    {'date': '2000-12-31 22:37:48'},
])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time

print(df)
print(df['time'].dtype)
print(type(df['time'][0]))
```

---

```
                 date      time
0 2000-12-31 22:12:40  22:12:40
1 2000-12-31 22:35:09  22:35:09
2 2000-12-31 22:32:48  22:32:48
3 2000-12-31 22:04:35  22:04:35
4 2001-01-06 23:38:11  23:38:11
5 2000-12-31 22:37:48  22:37:48
object
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

---

**Edit:**

Noticed your target was without the `date` column. Add the following to the end:

```
del df['date']
print(df)
```

---

```
       time
0  22:12:40
1  22:35:09
2  22:32:48
3  22:04:35
4  23:38:11
5  22:37:48
```

Answer (score 0):

Using: **datetime**

```
from datetime import datetime
your_datetime = "2017-01-01 23:00:00"
dt = datetime.strptime(your_datetime , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print dt
```

Comment: You should probably take into account the context. This was a pandas question. The answer should probably include how to do this column-by-column, not value-by-value. That said, some person will eventually end up here and find your answer enlightening.